# Spark RDD after splitting of data data type is changed how can i split without changing data type

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I have loaded data from text file to Spark RDD after splitting of data data type is changed. How can I split without changing data type or how can I convert split data to original data type?

**My code**

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext 
conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Movie") 
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf) 
movies = sc.textFile("file:///SaprkCourse/movie/movies.txt")
data=movies.map(lambda x: x.split(","))
data.collect()
```

**My input is like**

```
userId,movieId,rating,timestamp
1,1,4.0,964982703
1,3,4.0,964981247
1,6,4.0,964982224
1,47,5.0,964983815
1,50,5.0,964982931
```

**after splitting my complete data is changed to String type**

[image]

I required output to be same data type as in input text File, as `IntegerType, IntegerType, IntegerType, IntegerType`

Answer (score 0):

it seam that your data is csv,
you should use sparkSession, read the data with `csv` and define your schema.

scala code :

```
val schema = new Structype()
.add("userId",IntegerType)
.add("movieId",IntegerType)
.add("rating",IntegerType)
.add("timestamp",TimestampType)


spark.read.schema(schema).csv("file:///SaprkCourse/movie/movies.txt")
```

if you want to keep reading the file as text you can cast every column :

scala :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{IntegerType,TimestampType}

   val df = data
    .select(
    col("userId").cast(IntegerType),
    col("movieId").cast(IntegerType),
    col("rating").cast(IntegerType),
    col("timestamp").cast(TimestampType)
    )
```

Comment: Hi My input file is a Text file but not CSV

Comment: The CSV files are text, the point of this answer is that the data in your input text file is organized as CSV

Answer (score 0):

spark when reading a text file affect the type StringType to all columns so if you want to treat your columns as IntegerType you need to cast them.